# Installing FreePBX or Asiterisk-GUI on working server

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, configuration, freepbx

We have server with Ububuntu and asterisk 1.8 on it without any web-interfaces.

Our managers ask me to make them web-interface for looking over config, users, calls and so on.

I've installed asterisk-gui on this server but it didn't catch any configuration of trunks, sip accounts and so on, it's empty. Is this the way it should be or I'm mistaking somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

All the asterisk frontends I have used generated asterisk config files from their own config database.  They don't work the other way around.

If you want a GUI you are likely stuck reconfiguring asterisk from scratch using the new GUI and manually setting all the settings your existing config has.